# How do I create persistent executable files?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, chmod

I have created a script file called `restart-services.sh` and made it executable using `chmod +x`.

I run it to restart some services by simply double clicking on it and selecting run.

However, if I copy this file to a different system and double click, it will display the content of the file. I have to issue the `chmod +x restart-services.sh` command on any system I copy this file to in order to make it executable on the new system.

Is there a way I can make this file's executable feature persist across the board?

Comment: How did you copy the file?  Did you use `-p` to preserve file attributes?

Comment: no i didn't. just right-click copy and paste

Comment: Without release details, nor which file-manager you used (even if you're talking about `nautilus` without release details I can't know version details) but I'd copy & paste with options that preserve file attributes (date/time & other attributes like eXecute get kept)